# Why doesn't the view read cookies on AJAX refreshment?

Tags: views, 8, ajax, cookies

I use views_extras module to get default argument froom cookies.
It works ok.

But if I set a cookie value using javascript and then refresh a view using ajax the view still shows result for previous value.
So the new value affects only if I reload page.

Why and how to make ajax requests use current cookie?

Btw, I wrote my own module to read cookie value and use it as default 
argument: the result is the same with views_extras module.

Comment: Are the cookies HttpOnly?

Comment: no, this flag haven't set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that an ajax view already has argument stored in drupalSettings.views.ajaxViews["views_dom_id:..."].view_args

So the view gets this argument and use it instead of default argument from cookie. So we need to change the value of argument as well as cookie.